# How to use reduceByKey on key of value in tuple set up as (String, (String, Int))?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am attempting to loop through an RDD of a text file, and make a tally of each unique word in the file, and then accumulate all of the words that follow each unique word, along with their counts. So far, this is what I have:

```
// connecting to spark driver
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("WordStats").setMaster("local")
val spark = new SparkContext(conf) //Creates a new SparkContext object

//Loads the specified file into an RDD
val lines = sparkContext.textFile(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/" + "basketball_words_only.txt")

//Splits the file into individual words
val words = lines.flatMap(line => {

  val wordList = line.split(" ")

  for {i <- 0 until wordList.length - 1}

    yield (wordList(i), wordList(i + 1), 1)

})
```

[image: Output Generated By My Current MapReduce Program]

If I haven't been clear thus far, what I am trying to do is to accumulate the set of words that follow each word in the file, along with the number of times said words follow.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, we have something like this:

```
val lines: Seq[String] = ...
val words: Seq[(String, String, Int)] = ...
```

And we want something like this:

```
val frequencies: Map[String, Seq[(String, Int)]] = {
  words
    .groupBy(_._1)                        // word -> [(w, next, cc), ...]
    .mapValues { values =>
      values
        .map { case (w, n, cc) => (n, cc) }
        .groupBy(_._1)                    // next -> [(next, cc), ...]
        .mapValues(_.reduce(_._2 + _._2)) // next -> sum
        .toSeq
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @adu! You seem to understand exactly what I'm looking for, however, when I attempt to add this code to my own, I am met with two errors at compile time, which are as follows:                                                       Error:(92, 36) type mismatch;
 found   : Int
 required: (String, Int)
          .mapValues(_.reduce(_._2 + _._2)) // next -> sum <br> Error:(93, 12) type mismatch;
 found   : Seq[(String, (String, Int))]
 required: Seq[(String, Int)]
          .toSeq  with your code being placed in lines 85-95